# Excel macro - open specific word file

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I haven't found anything that can help me.

I'm trying to open a certain word file, have some data written in it and saved under a different name. This is what I have so far:

```
Dim appWD As Word.Application
Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application.8")
Set appWD = New Word.Application
Dim docWD As Word.Document
Set docWD = appWD.Documents.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\Excel macro\Standaard.docx")
appWD.Visible = True
'
' Data is selected and copied into "Design"
'
 Copy all data from Design
Sheets("Design").Select
Range("A1:G50").Copy
' Tell Word to create a new document
appWD.Documents.Add
' Tell Word to paste the contents of the clipboard into the new document
appWD.Selection.Paste
' Save the new document with a sequential file name
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "TEST" & Range("C8").Text
' Close this new word document
appWD.ActiveDocument.Close
' Close the Word application
appWD.Quit
```

At the moment all it does is; open the Standaard.docx file, open a new file and paste everything in the new file and saves. It should open the Standaard.docx file, paste it in there and save under a new name.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it opens a new document is because you have the line:

```
appWD.Documents.Add
```

in your code before the line:

```
appWD.Selection.Paste
```

if you remove the `appWD.Documents.Add` Word will paste into your active document (i.e. "Standaard.docx").

Just one other point, you do not need the line:

```
Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application.8")
```

as you immediately initialise a new Word application in the line below it with:

```
Set appWD = New Word.Application
```

Answer (score 0):

This macro opens a file then saves it as a new file name in a different folder based on info updated in the sheet1 of the Excel file

```
Sub OpenDocFileNewName()


'
' OpenDocFileNewName Macro

'
'
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application.8")

Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\mmezzolesta\Documents\_TestDataMerge\STANDARD.docx")

WordApp.Visible = True

'
'
'Save as new file name

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=("C:\Users\mmezzolesta\Documents\_TestMailMergeAuto") & "/" & Range("A2") & "Standard-Grounding-" & Range("e2").Text

WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close

WordApp.Quit

'
'
End Sub
```